# Can someone recommend a good reference for learning the basics of server side scripting

Tags: python

I want to learn server-side scripting. Since I know some Python, probably that would be the best to start with (tell me if I am wrong). The problem is that I do not know even the basics of server side scripting. Is there a good book or tutorial that can help me get started?

I know there are many web frameworks in python - flask, bottle, django, cherrypy etc. But before I start reading the manual of one of these, are there other basics to learn.

I know basic HTML, CSS and I am currently learning basic Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: are you willing to try out django1.3? I am currently working in it. It's quite handy and fun to work with.

Comment: I don't know if this is the place for your question, but I will offer my opinion. I feel like you could jump into a web framework. Personally, I thought Django was fairly easy to pick up, as its tutorial and documentation are quite extensive and helpful. It's also possible to do some server-side scripting with plain Python, and if you prefer, you can play around with that before jumping into a framework.

However, if you prefer to keep learning JavaScript instead, you can look up information about AJAX, which should help you gain some insight into working with server-side programming.

Comment: @U-DON - Thanks! Is there a reference that shows/teaches how to do server side scripting with plain Python? That would be great before I jump into a framework, especially something as involved as Django.

Comment: Look up CGI and Python. Upon a quick search, I found this: http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/sd99east/sld039.htm. It's been a while since I did CGI scripting with Python, and I only played around with that for a short time before I went into frameworks. Still, this should help you understand some basic server-side programming.

Comment: Thanks U-DON. This was good, but I found better (more detailed) information in the books I mention in the my post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some good references on Python Web Programming page that I had not seen earlier. You can see them if you scroll down to Books and Articles section on  http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks page. As stated there, Lutz's Programming Python contains a lot of information on internet programming. You will see some other references there, such as Wesley Chun's book, which gives a very good explanation of client and server concepts.